# Can tailwind add prefixes to skip px2rem checks?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, vite

I am writing a vue project where I use rem for large screen adaptations, but I don't want to use px2rem for certain files.

I tried changing "exclude" in the configuration file, and it worked, but it didn't work when I used tailwind in the tag because tailwind is a global selector, So I figured out if I could add a selector to tailwind and use the "selectorBlackList"  configuration to do that

like:

```html
<div class="text-[12px]"></div>

After compiling:

//Skip the px2rem check by "ignore"
.ignore.text-[12px]{
  font-size: 12px
}
```

Or do you have a better idea for what I want?